# Please help I have this and I didn't get it well

Tags: limits

How to solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{1}{x-2}$?

I tried to solve it by dividing the both sides on $x$ but it doesn't work and I tried to get the dam $-2$ out but also didnt work so how to solve it I know that there is no limit for this but how to Remove the  indeterminacy

Comment: The limit does not exist. Is that what you wish to show?

Comment: What indeterminacy do you need to remove?  You are dividing by something that is approaching $0.$  That is usually sufficient.  If you want to be very rigorous say $M$ is your upper bound.  For an $M,$ you can find an $x$ in the neighborhood of $2$ such that $f(x) > M.$  Then show that there is also an x in the neighborhood such that $f(x) < - M$

Comment: Not all limits that appear undefined can be made prettier to have an answer.

Comment: Plotting a graph or checking a table of values always serve to give some light when you find a problem difficult to solve, as knowing the answer helps guide the way.

Comment: And welcome to [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)!  We hope you truly enjoy and I welcome you be presenting the magic [MathJax Handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Related: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to4}\frac{1}{x-4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921633/201168).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you should show the limit doesn't exist.  Start by assuming they exist and that

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac1{x-2}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac1u\tag{$x-2=u$}$$

Now, consider $u\to0^+$ and $u\to0^-$.  Since we have

$$-\left(\frac1u\right)=\frac1{(-u)}$$

We must have

$$\underbrace{\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac1u}_L=\lim_{u\to0^-}\frac1{(-u)}=\underbrace{-\left(\lim_{u\to0^-}\frac1u\right)}_{-L}$$

Since, for the limit to exist, we must have the limit from the left equal the limit from the right, which in turn equal the limit from both sides, we end up with the following statement:

$$L=-L$$

where $L=\lim_{u\to0}\frac1u$.  Solving this gives $L=0$, which isn't true since as $u\to0$, $\frac1u$ gets farther and farther from $0$.  Thus, the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Hm, does assuming the limit exists mean that the limit is equal to the average of it's left and right limits?

Comment: It seems odd to start your argument by seeing that two "limits" that don't exist are equal.

Comment: @Airymouse Well, if you assume they exist, then they are equal.  If one doesn't exist, then both don't exist.

Comment: There's a story that someone asked Bertrand Russell to assume that 1=2 and prove he was the Pope. Russell said,"the Pope and I are two, so the Pope and I are one."  So you could just as well say, if you assume they exist, then they are unequal. What you are using is that if the  limit on the right-hand side of your equation does not exist, then neither does the limit on the left-hand side. I'm guessing the questioner will have as much difficulty seeing this proposition as the one he queried.

Answer (score 0):

You perform sign analysis with 1.9 and 2.1. If x = 1.9, then $\frac{1}{x-2}$ will be negative. If x = 2.1, then it will be positive. Thus, the limit approaching from the left is negative infinity and the limit approaching from the right is positive infinity, so the limit as x goes to 2 **does not exist**.

Comment: This is... sort of true. However, think of something like $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. Your analysis crashes and burns here

Comment: Thanks guys you for helping me

Comment: @KazemJalabi Always welcomed.